# Video with transparency shows black when looking from behind a tranparent material

Tags: transparency, video

So I'm making this animation where the camera is first person and from inside a car, but the model I got had opaque window material, so I turned the material alpha to 0, but now, when looking from behind it, the stickman video shows black like that, anyone got a solution?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: if youre going to use an alpha of 0 then try disabling the window altogether (dont delete it)

Comment: That’s not how alpha works @desperrrr…

Comment: please provide blend file since you didn't show us any of your settings

Comment: this is the blender project file:
https://we.tl/t-zooiNODBKJ

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.